# Is it possible to use spring message tags in a non-Spring-MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, struts

I have a `Struts`2 application in which I am currently using `Spring Securit`y and `Spring DI`, but my MVC framework is Struts2. I was wondering whether I can use `spring form tag`s in the JSP. My basic requirement is to use `Spring internationalizatio`n features at the JSP level.

Comment: I have been able to use Spring security tags without any problem.. but I am not sure if variables set in Struts 2 action classes will be accessible using Spring tags. I want to know the rationale - trying out will give me the answer to whether they work on not but not the rationale